# Pointer to class

Tags: c++, pointers, operator-overloading

I have been trying to write a Fraction class and overload some of its operators (+, -, -, /...). At first, I tried to do it like this:

```
Fraction& operator+(Fraction& rightOp)
{
    Fraction result;
    result.num = num * rightOp.den + den * rightOp.num;
    result.den = den * rightOp.den;;
    return result;
}
```

This produced an awkward result. While testing, if I used:

```
Fraction a(2,3);
Fraction b(4,5);
Fraction c = a + b;
cout << c << endl;
```

It would print correctly. However, if I used:

```
Fraction a(2,3);
Fraction b(4,5);
Fraction c;
c = a + b;
cout << c << endl;
```

It would print -858993460/-858993460.

Then, when I tried to change the overloading function to:

```
Fraction& operator+(Fraction& rightOp)
{
    Fraction* result = new Fraction;
    result->num = num * rightOp.den + den * rightOp.num;
    result->den = den * rightOp.den;
    return *result;
}
```

It would all work well. This got me confused about pointing to classes in C++, I do not really understand why the first one fails in a specific case. I would appreciate any explanation.

Thanks in advance.

Note:
Operator << is not the source of the problem but here it is anyway:

```
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, Fraction& f)
{
    out << f.num << "/" << f.den << endl;
    return out;
}
```

Comment: Please post the complete class, particularly the assignment operators. Also, your second example leaks memory, and both examples fail to reduce the fraction. Also, you aren't following const correctness.

Comment: If you do a bunch of adds, you may find the denominator overflows.  You might consider using result.den = gcd( den , rightOp.den );

Comment: I was not really trying to write a fully functional and perfect Fraction class, it was an assignment for me to get a hang of overloading operators, so I did not bother with gcd.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Fraction& operator+(Fraction& rightOp)
{
    Fraction result;
    result.num = num * rightOp.den + den * rightOp.num;
    result.den = den * rightOp.den;;
    return result;
}
```

The problem with this is that it's returning a reference to a local variable. The local variable is destroyed when the function ends, so the reference refers to an invalid object.

Using `new` instead has solved the problem for you because it makes the `result` object dynamically allocated. Such an object is *not* destroyed at the end of the function. However, it is certainly not the solution here. It is completely unclear to the user of `operator+` that the reference returned refers to a dynamically allocated object and needs to be `delete`d in the future. Never put that burden on your users.

Instead, you should just change the function so that it returns by value:

```
Fraction operator+(Fraction& rightOp)
{
  // ...
  return result;
}
```

This will now return a *copy* of `result`, so it doesn't matter if `result` is destroyed at the end of the function.

As an additional note, you probably want the function to take a `const Fraction&` argument. This allows it to be called when the second operand is an rvalue (typically a temporary object).

Comment: It should ideally be a free function that takes const references.

Answer (score 2):

Your `+` overload returns an instance of `Fraction` *by-reference*. The problem is that the local instance of `Fraction` will go out of scope at the end of the expression `a + b`, but `c` will still hold a reference to that empty spot in memory.

Return by-reference is not what you want here. It's more suitable to make a copy in this case by returning by-*value*:

```
Fraction operator +(Fraction& rightOp)
{
    Fraction result;
    result.num = num * rightOp.den + den * rightOp.num;
    result.den = den * rightOp.den;;
    return result;
}
```

Moreover, it's recommended that your `>>` overload take a `Fraction` instance by *`const`* reference, since it does not modify it inside the body:

```
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, Fraction const& f)
//                                                ^^^^^
```